# div comes in from left bottom rather than dropping down

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery hide with a toggle...basically I am trying to do an accordion but client wants the ability to have multiple content areas open at same time.

All is going ok but I can't figure out how to control the look of how the text animates. Ideally, I just want it to slide down from below the header. Bit it seems to appear from the right bottom corner.

here's my html:

```
<div id="accordion">

  <h3 class="dropdown dropdown-default-on">About Me</h3>
  <div id='about-div'>
    <p>Some info about Me. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>

  <h3 class="dropdown">My Skills</h3>
  <div id='about-div'>
    <p>Some info about my Skills. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hmhU/)

Comment: use `slideToggle` instead of `toggle`..

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using slideDown(300) and slideUp(300) from the jQuery library, to slide up and down? You could use those + a global variable that tracks position (up vs down) and then an if statement in the onClick, that checks its position and slides up or down accordiongly (heh).

Comment: You maybe are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/9hmhU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated you fiddle

[Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/9hmhU/2/)

Here's the updated code

```
jQuery( function() {
     $('.dropdown').click(function() {
         if($(this).next().is(":visible")){
    $(this).next().slideUp(300);
         }
         else{
         $(this).next().slideDown(300);
         }
    return false;
  } ).next().hide();

    $('.dropdown-default-on').next().toggle(300);

       } );
```

Comment: This is what I needed, as a few others noted...slideup and slidedown. Thank you Akshay.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `slideToggle()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9hmhU/5

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('.dropdown').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Other notes: I removed some code that didn't seem to be doing anything. Also, you have duplicate ID values, which isn't allowed. Finally, the TidyUp button is your friend. :-)

Comment: By the way, it's the min-height on your divs that causes that jump. Maybe move that to a child element: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9hmhU/6